# retrieve blob file stored in database php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to retrieve the blob file i have stored in the database and create link for download or view of file. I am retrieving the data entry database like

```
if ($stmt - > rowCount() > 0) {
    while ($selected_row = $stmt - > fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $basicinfo[] = array('remarks' => $selected_row['remarks'], 'filename' => $selected_row['nameoffile'], 'type' => $selected_row['file_type'], 'size' => $selected_row['filesize']);

    }
}
```

The column name of the blob file is `fileblob` what i try is i added `'fileblob' => $selected_row['fileblob']` when i add this to the code then i get no result. I want to know how to correctly retrieve a blob file and then be able to show/download it using a link.

`FYI`

My database looks like this.

[image]

Comment: What does your query look like?

Comment: @Darren select all i mean `$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM (tables here)`